# R - Can I make R recognize if name of column is part of value?

Tags: r, binary

[image]

As you can see the data is very big. Naming the columns in the code is therefore no option. I honestly have no idea how to solve that problem.

Btw, if it is too complicated because of the one ID column, I can also divide it into more ID variables. Like this:

[image]

Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can we do it for a row, say length 11? If so, we can do it for a data.frame. Your sense that `+` in ID is perhaps an annoyance is agreed. Doing this for a small row is like making a minimal working example. Our friends `gsub`, `names`, and `strsplit` can help here.
First we'll make a representative 'row':

```
name_col <- c('ID', '10', '600', '2000', '76', '240', '42', '3010', '999', '3000', '6')
```

You'd get the names of all columns in your data.frame with:

```
my_df_names <- names(my_df)
```

but we'll stick with our row above and create an index of ID elements in column names with column names first:

```
> row_idx <- name_col %in% unlist(strsplit(gsub(' + ', ' ', ID_with_plus, fixed = TRUE), ' '))
> row_idx
 [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

This seems favorable, so assign the result, by row, use the indexes to set your 1/0 values by index. The next part is creating and using the indices iteratively. I would generally start with a `for` loop, but first we'll make an empty list to receive all the indexes. We already have `my_df_names`, and we're going to point our `unlist(strsplit(gsub(' + ', ' ', ID_with_plus, fixed = TRUE), ' '))` to my_df$ID, instead of the previous example row:

```
my_many_idxs <- list()
for (j in 1:nrow(my_df) {
my_many_idxs[[j]] <- my_df_names %in% unlist(strsplit(gsub(' + ', ' ', my_df$ID[j], fixed = TRUE), ' '))
}
```

This will hopefully result in a 300k length list. If your memory blows up, maybe you do 100k at a time. Now do another `for` loop setting the values using the indexes. Note the difference `[[` and `[` used above, `[[` for list values and `[` for vector. We already have 'my_df' and we have 'my_many_idxs', so we don't need to make an object to receive.

```
for (k in 1:length(my_many_idxs) {
my_df[k, ] <- ifelse(my_many_idxs[[k]], 1, 0)
}
```

I think gets us there, but I don't have the 300kx4k df, so imagining this will work. Again, note `[[` for things from lists, `[` for things from vector. Let me know.

Comment: Great, that works fine with the my_df_names <- names(my_df) command. Substituting the TRUEs and FALSEs with Ones and Zeros will be no problem. But how can I automate that process to all other rows. Right now I only have the TRUEs and FALSEs for the row chosen. But I have about 300k rows and can´t type every row by hand.

Comment: Rounding this out, tentatively, but I think it should work.